# I have a table, this table contains attributes written in GML and I want to transfer these GML to geometry in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql

[image]

Some attribute written as a .GML file in PostgreSQL and I want to transfer these GML to polygon, so that the table becomes a vector table.

Comment: Je ne pa parlais francais. Please post your question in English, in order to allow all users to participate. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: You must tell where the geometries would come from. If already in the GML, just "save as" Shapefile. / Tu dois dire d'ou viendraient les geometries. Si elles sont deja dans le GML, tu peux faire un "sauvegarder sous" en Shapefile.

Answer (score 2):

You should convert GML geometry into PostGIS native (WKB) geometry and update the new column with the GML geometry:

```
CREATE EXTENSION PostGIS; -- if not enabled yet
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN the_geom geom(MULTIPOLYGON, 32630);
UPDATE TABLE your_table SET the_geom = ST_GeomFromGML(geom);
```

You can drop geom column with GML geometry, and you can directly use this table from QGIS after creating a connection to your database from QGIS.